# Cocoa bindings. Not updating properties in UI

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a model with a `User` class. The user has a `picture` `NSImage` attribute (set transformable in coredata). What I want to do is to retrieve the picture from the server the first time it is accessed.

A first solution (which works but I don't like) is to add a category and another NSImage property. The UI is bounded to this second property. The first time it is accessed it connects to the server and it retrieves the image.
The problem with this solution is that I have to pass to this class the reference to the httpclient (I use AFNetworking, so `AFHTTPClient`) which I create and initialize in my appdelegate. Currently it is a singleton but I don't like this solution.

So… this is the second thing I'm trying:
I created the following method in my `AFHTTPClient` wrapper class

```
- (void)loadPictureForUser:(User*)user
       imageLoadedCallback:(void(^)())callback
{
    //if picture is already loaded do nothing
    if (user.picture) return;
    //if the request is already "ongoing" then do nothing
    if ([self.imageLoadingRequests objectForKey:user.id]) return;

    //We have to make a request
    //set the placeholder while we wait for the image
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    user.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UnknownUserPicture"];
#else
    user.picture = [NSImage imageNamed:@"UnknownUserPicture"];
#endif

    //make the request
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"id" : user.id,
                             @"size" : @(80),
                             @"count" : @(random() % 1000000)};

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = self.httpClient;
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                          path:ServerGetUserPictureURL
                                                    parameters:params];

    __weak ConnectionManager *weakSelf = self;
    AFImageRequestOperation *imageRequestOperation =
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageRequest
                                         imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                                          user.picture = image;
                                                          //in every case I have to remove the entry from the dictionary
                                                          [weakSelf.imageLoadingRequests removeObjectForKey:user.id];
                                                          BLOCK_SAFE_EXEC(callback);
                                                      }
                                                      failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                          //in every case I have to remove the entry from the dictionary
                                                          [weakSelf.imageLoadingRequests removeObjectForKey:user.id];
                                                      }];

#else
    [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageRequest
                                         imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSImage *image) {
                                                          //save the picture in the user

                                                          user.picture = image;
                                                          user.picture.name = user.nickname;


                                                          //in every case I have to remove the entry from the dictionary
                                                          [weakSelf.imageLoadingRequests removeObjectForKey:user.id];
                                                          BLOCK_SAFE_EXEC(callback);

                                                      } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                          //in every case I have to remove the entry from the dictionary
                                                          [weakSelf.imageLoadingRequests removeObjectForKey:user.id];
                                                      }];
#endif

    [self.imageLoadingRequests setObject:imageRequestOperation forKey:user.id];
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:imageRequestOperation];
}
```

This method set a placeholder until it retrieves the correct picture.
This method is called from a custom `NSValueTransformer`

```
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    if (![value isKindOfClass:[User class]])
        return nil;
    User *user = value;

    [self.connectionManager loadPictureForUser:value imageLoadedCallback:NULL];
    return user.picture;
}
```

The placeholder is correctly set (obviously).
The problem is that when the correct picture is set the UI is not updated.
I think this can be a problem on how I bind the properties…

I use it in two different places:

- a simple `NSImageView`.. I bind the `value` attribute directly to the fileowner.connectionManger.user (fileowner is an `NSWindowController` subclass, and the connectionmanager keeps track of the user which is logged in) and then I set the transformer on it.
- an `NSTableView`. The `NSArrayController` is bound to an `NSArray` containing object of class `News`. Each of this has a property `creator` which is a `User` object.. So the imageview inside the row in the table is bound to `objectValue.creator` and then the same transformer.

Some ideas on why this does not work?

EDIT: I removed my statement about ''programmatically'' works.
I saw it working but maybe it was for some other reason.
So… when I set the `user.picture` value no KVO notification are sent to my observing object…
I am starting to think I do not handle correctly the KVO protocol but I read the guide and still I can't figure out the error.

For the first ''case'' (`NSImageView` binding) the user object I bound is inside the wrapper. So if I understand correctly also the wrapper should be KVO compliant for the user object. But I think it is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) User *user;
```

And of course the `User` object is a `NSManagedObject` subclass (but my controller has no relation with the `NSMangedObjectContext`.. but I don't think this is the issue…